# Firebase Auth.auth().createUser Method skipped ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

Hi I am currently using firebase, I have been trying to create a new users using Auth.auth().createUser Method but when I run my program it reaches the method but skips over it. I have haven't received any error messages.if anyone have a solution please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on that line to see if it's actually even hitting that line?

Comment: You should include the code you're asking about. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth.auth().createUser is an async method, which takes some time to execute.

If you are returning from the function, you shouldn't return from this function, what you should do instead is use a callback.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it's a bit premature to post this as an answer since there's absolutely no code in the question and we don't know what 'skips over it' means - that would indicate the code in the closure is not running at all. That being said - you're probably correct but I like to get more info before jumping to a conclusion.

Comment: Thank you that helped understand where my code should be placed